# How to delete a SQLite database information

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile

```
public void excluir (int codigo){

    String[] parametros = new String[1];
    parametros[0] = String.valueOf(codigo);

    conexao.delete("CLIENTE", "CODIGO = ? ", parametros);}
```

Here is the code to exclude an information of my table.

Here / i have the method View View that is called by a button

```
public void tirar (View view){
    int x = 1;
    ClienteRepositorio clienteRepositorio = new ClienteRepositorio(conexao);
    clienteRepositorio.excluir(x);
    onResume();

}
```

And this is the class where I create my table:

```
public class ScriptDLL {

    public static String getCreateTableCliente(){
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CLIENTE (");
        sql.append("       CODIGO       INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,");
        sql.append("       NOME         VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),");
        sql.append("       ENDERECO     VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),");
        sql.append("       EMAIL        VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),");
        sql.append("       TELEFONE     VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL DEFAULT ('') )");
        return sql.toString();
    }
}
```

So, if I'm right, it should work, it should give `1` when you click the button and then the method should start and delete the information, but nothing really happens when the button is pressed. What should be the reason?

Thanks
Vanderval

Comment: I think u need to add `DROP TABLE CLIENTE  IF EXISTS`  and then simple `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: are you getting any error? check your log

Comment: Rehan, where should i put this? I wiil be deleting all the table?

Comment: Jyoti JK, nothing shows up.

Comment: Stop asking duplicates and get to understand the basics of what you are trying to do first. Go through a tutorial for God's sake.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete hall database then used below code ..

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

When this line gets run, the database should be deleted.Make sure you close all Database connections before deleting. Else you'll have to restart the application.

and only delete table then used below query

```
 db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_TABLE_NAME);
```

Comment: Thanks man, but i need to delete only an information, not all the table. Ayway, thanks a lot

Comment: delete table record it means?

Comment: yep. sorry about my english

Answer (score 0):

delete table record used below code..

```
    public void deleteTableItem(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id =" + id, null);
    db.close();
}
```

this code put in your database class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper.
and pass only id for particular record.